# macOS Sierra breaks a lot of terminal "defaults write" commands (tap to click for example)

Tags: terminal, macos, trackpad

I have my [shell-scripts](https://github.com/komarnicki/shell-scripts/blob/master/macOS/adjust.sh) where I adjust bunch of settings in batch to customise macOS to my needs. In terms of Trackpad, I like "tap to click".

I use

```
echo "Adjusting Trackpad."
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -bool true # enable "Tap To Click" feature
defaults -currentHost write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 1
defaults write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 1
```

But apparently this stopped working in Sierra. What's more funny. These 3 `defaults` do toggle the checkbox if you manually go to

> System Preferences -> Trackpad -> Tap to click

**but the change is not reflected**!

Manual untick and tick of that checkbox in GUI, applies tap to click straight away. Am I the only one who's facing such an issue?

Sierra breaks a lot of other stuff. Like permissions for `brew install xxx` but that deserves another topic. In general I'm extremely disappointed.

Comment: Every major release always breaks and or changes something, that's just the way it is and always will be! As far as `defaults` goes, ever since Yosemite there has been major issues with using `defaults` to change settings more so then previously and back then there were lots of discussions on the Internet about how OS X had changed and why `defaults` doesn't work like it use to. When something no longer works because of whatever changes are made in each release you just have to find another alternative when the old method no longer works. See if using PlistBuddy makes a difference.

Comment: Indeed, Terminal commands that once adjusted key repeat rates and mission control animation speeds no longer work either. I saw an image on twitter (in Japanese which I don't read) that seemed to say that Apple rewrote Mission Control and presumably other stuff in Swift, so perhaps that is the issue. Hopefully someone smarter than I will develop some work arounds.

Comment: Keep in mind - asking "does anyone have this issue" is a yes/no question that generally gets people answering yes and another answer no and then people vote on the choices. Are you trying to do something specific or just document Item X is now broken?

Comment: Yes- I have just tried to change the default Sierra Dock from 2D to 3D:
"defaults write com.apple.dock no-glass -boolean NO" followed by "kill Dock"
and it is not working.
No complaints, just does not seem to do anything.